# Keep running an action after user closes broswer

Tags: asp.net, node.js, server, cron, cgi

I know this may not be an ideal stackoverflow question but I'm not sure where else to ask. To cut a long story short, I've built a web app running on a LAN network. The reason for this is that it is located somewhere there is very limited internet access. But there is one part of the app that needs to connect to the outside internet with Twilio.

So basically my question is, how do I get the script to keep trying to send the text message even if the user exits the session? Would some kind of cron job work or would I better off using asp.net or node.js? Or could a cgi script do it? Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm not overly familiar with how servers and all that actually work.

Thanks guys, let me know if anything needs clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fire and forget approach; however, it is not recommended.

```
Task.Run(() => StartLongRunningProcess());
```

Instead, you might want to consider using Background Tasks such as [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

[How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely look into that. It actually looks a lot simpler than I was expecting it to be

Comment: After going through the documentation, hangfire is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for bringing it to my attention